# google api to search nearby address using their latitude,longitude from database

Tags: google-maps

I need to retrieve a set of nearby addresses from google api using their latitude,longitude values.Latitude,longitude values are retrieved from a database.Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Maps Javascript Api.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

And Read a developer guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done with a combination of jquery and the google api. the $.getJSON call is invoking a service that gets a list of lat/lng objects in a pretty standard name and address kind of format and pushes everything into a marker array.

In this example the user enters an address in the "useradd" control, which becomes one blue marker, and some nearby things in the database are displayed as red markers.

I have found the map to be very sensitive to styling changes, especially modifying it's height and width, I am sure there is some way to deal with that, just have not found it yet.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);  //add some real starting coords
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        $('#loadMsg').hide().ajaxStart(function () { $(this).show(); }).ajaxStop(function () { $(this).hide(); });
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function getStringfromJSON(invalue) {
        if (!invalue) { return ''; } else { return invalue; }
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("useradd").value;
        if (address.length == 0) return;

        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
        }

        geocoder.geocode
        (
            { 'address': address },
            function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var blueIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png");
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location, icon: blueIcon, clickable: false });
                    marker.setTitle(address);

                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    var dist = document.getElementById("selMiles").value;

                    var pageurl = '../Search/GetNearbys?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng + '&dist=' + dist;
                    $.getJSON(pageurl,
                                function (data) {
                                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                                        var facid = data[x].ID;
                                        var facname = getStringfromJSON(data[x].Name);
                                        var streetaddress = getStringfromJSON(data[x].StreetAddress);
                                        var address2 = getStringfromJSON(data[x].Address2);
                                        var city = getStringfromJSON(data[x].City);
                                        var state = getStringfromJSON(data[x].State);
                                        var zip = getStringfromJSON(data[x].ZipCode);
                                        var xlat = data[x].Latitude;
                                        var xlng = data[x].Longitude;
                                        var xlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(xlat, xlng);
                                        var xmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: xlatlng, facilityid: facid });
                                        xmarker.setTitle(facname + ' ' + streetaddress + ' ' + address2 + ' ' + city + ',' + state + ' ' + zip);
                                        markersArray.push(xmarker);

                                        google.maps.event.addListener(xmarker, 'click',
                                            function () {
                                                window.open('../Profile?id=' + this.facilityid, '_blank');
                                            });
                                    }
                                },
                                function (succeess) { }
                            );
                }
                else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
                markersArray.push(marker);  //put it here so it gets reset after each search
            }
       );
    }

</script>
```